# VS2017 fails to create appxupload-package of headless IoT app for store publishing

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10-universal, publishing, windows-10-iot-core, headless

I want to publish a headless UWP application for Windows 10 IoT Core devices to the app store, but fail to build the neccessary appxupload-package.

The app itself is a simple background task that reacts to the push of a button and communicates with a web service using SignlR. The project template can be found here: [Windows IoT Core Project Templates for VS 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MicrosoftIoT.WindowsIoTCoreProjectTemplatesforVS15)

There is a guide for publishing UWP apps to the store, including special instructions for headless apps: [Installing and Servicing apps on Windows 10 IoT Core](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/store)

I follow this instructions step by step but still Visual Studio 2017 fails to build the appxupload-package (error message: "ilc.exe exited with code 1004"). If I try to build the solution I get following error: "Applications with custom entry point executables are not supported".

I did not do any other relevant modifications to the Manifest beside those mentioned in the instructions.
Also, without this modifications to the Manifest, Visual Studio 2017 succeeds creating the appxupload-package - but I can't use that one since it won't be accepted by the store because of it's headless nature.

I really have no clue about how to make this work and hope somebody can help me with this problem here! I didn't find any other information about this problem anywhere else.

Comment: Have you build your app with this **Release** configuration?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Yes, I did right away! And I did it again just now - just to be sure. Also, I did the whole process with another but very similar app. But still, the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create the appxupload-package. Turns out the guide to publish headless apps to the appstore has some issues.

The guide is written using markdown and some of the information contained simply gets cut off when rendered for viewing purpose.

Since the guide is available via github repository you can use the raw version for full information: [Installing and servicing applications](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-iotcore-docs/live/windows-iotcore/commercialize-your-device/InstallingAndServicing.md)

**UPDATE**

The guide has been updated and issues have been solved - [Installing and Servicing applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/commercialize-your-device/InstallingAndServicing)